# Why are these lists not equivalent in Erlang?

Tags: list, erlang

I am trying to understand the usage of `|` in Erlang ,more specifically why is this expression not equivalent:

`[4,5,6|7]=:=[4,5,6,7]`

Isn't the `|` symbol used just for pattern matching , just to break the list in order to match it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pipe `|` in order to create a proper list needs a list on the right side. To this right side the pipe appends elements from the left side. So to create `[4, 5, 6, 7]` with the pipe you need

```
[4, 5, 6 | [7]]
```

The version you tried creates so called *improper list*. You can read more about it at [Understanding Lists](https://michal.muskala.eu/2015/10/16/understanding-lists.html).

Answer (score 7):

> Isn't the | symbol used just for pattern matching.

No, the *cons* (constructor) operator, `|`, can be used to both deconstruct a list with pattern matching and construct a list.  Often, the last line of a function will be:

```
 my_func(tail, [Head|Acc])
```

In that line, the cons operator creates a list for the second argument.  The second argument is a list which adds the contents of the variable `Head` to the front of the `Acc` list.

Here is an example using the cons operator to both deconstruct a list and construct a list:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

get_evens(List) -> 
    get_evens(List, []). %% Add an empty list to the function call to accumulate the results.

get_evens([Head|Tail], Acc) when Head rem 2 == 0 ->  %% deconstruct the first argument into Head and Tail
    get_evens(Tail, [Head|Acc]);  %% construct the second argument for the get_evens() function call
get_evens([_Head|Tail], Acc) ->
    get_evens(Tail, Acc);
get_evens([], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

In the shell:

```
2> c(a).
{ok,a}

3> a:get_evens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).
[2,4]

4>
```

The whole reason we can write recursive functions that will end when the empty list is found is because a list can be defined like this:

```
4> [1|[2|[3|[4|[5|[]]]]]].
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Note how 5 is cons'ed with the empty list: `5|[]`?  That means when you get to the end of a list,`[LastElmt | Tail]` will match `LastElmt` to `5` and `Tail` to `[]`, which means we can match a different function clause when we call `get_evens(Tail, Acc)`, e.g.:

```
get_evens([], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the use of the `|`, but related to your question about pattern matching. The `=` is used for assignment, but because data is immutable in erlang, it is also a basic pattern match and test for equivalency.

[Match Operator = in Patterns](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#match-operator-=-in-patterns)